# jqgrid / Validation of ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, jqgrid

I'm trying to create "validation" which is about "ID" in jqgrid to use 'custom' and 'custom_func'.

This is the custom function to test the value of id whether the id is combined with number and english(a-z) properly.

```
function id_validation(value, colname) {
var idReg = /[^a-z|^0-9]/gi;
if (!idReg.test(value)) {
    alert("ID는 영숫자 조합만 사용하세요");
    }
}
```

This is the column name,'USER_ID', which i want to apply the above function so i used the 'custom' and 'cusotm_func' in 'editrules'.

```
colModel: [               
            {name: 'USER_ID', index: 'USER_ID', editable: true, sortable: false, search: false, editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: id_validation}} ],
```

This code is execute very well unless i put the right value however, the biggest problem is it shows me the alert even if i put right value. It alerts every situation regardless of the values. Did i miss something? What parts do i have to fix?

Comment: have you tried with `.match()` instead of `.test()`?

Comment: @Jai Yes, I've tried it first but it didn't react anything so i modified to .test().

Comment: So you want to test if the entered ID only has alphanumerical chars?

Comment: @Vajura Absolutely. yes i want only alphanumerical chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of validation is not displaying of validation message. One should just inform jqGrid whether the input valid or not. In case of invalid input the *string* with the error message should be returned.  So the `id_validation` function should return `[true]` (array with one `true` element) or `[true, ""]` in case of no error and returns array like `[false, "error message"]` in case of wrong input data. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules). So the code should be about the following:

```
function id_validation (value, colname) {
    return /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test(value) ? 
        [true] :
        [false, "ID는 영숫자 조합만 사용하세요"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a regex that matches any non alphanumerical char in a string you can simply use

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z]
```

You can also simply add a **_** if you want that to be valid also like this

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z_]
```

So a .test(string) should match now if there is any symbol in it that has any non alphanumerical char in it and it will not match if every char is either a letter or a number (or underline if you want to include that)

Comment: I've modified the regex same as written above but i don't know the reason why it couldn't validate the alphanumerical characters.

Comment: This regex will return a match IF there is a char in the string that isnt a alphanumerical char so afewa543fdsa wont match while awgffewa!54 will match

Comment: I tried with your chars and i've got a different situation. "Custom function should return array!" is showed. Do you know why?

Comment: You can check it here how this regex works http://regex101.com/r/eD8iY7/1 , i dont know how you are doing your implementation of it

Comment: Yes, I checked how it works and i found that the value must contains "!!" exclamation marks.